# having OneHotEncoder to manage unseen values at transform step

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn

I am using [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) to encode categorical data of the form

```
A=array([[1,4,1],[0,3,2]])
B=array([[1,4,7],[0,3,2]])
```

Suppose I use `A` at the `.fit(A)` step and `B` at some point as new data to `.transform(B)`. If `B` contains unseen values in respect to `A`, doing so produces a `feature out of bounds error`. Is it possible to have `B` containing new unseen values such that the transform step sets all binaries to zero for the concerned value?

```
ValueError: Feature out of bounds. Try setting n_values.
```

I understand I can change the feature bounds at `.fit` time. But if I am using `A` as training data, each time I got a new set B to predict, I would have to mess with my initial encoding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have B containing new unseen values such that the transform step sets all binaries to zero for the concerned value?

No, but it would be nice if `OneHotEncoder` did that, so I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2169) for this. For now, you'll just have to set `n_values` a bit higher.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is added to OneHotEncoder now. You can do this by setting the parameter `handle_unknown='ignore'`.

For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

A=array([[1,4,1],[0,3,2]])
B=array([[1,4,7],[0,3,2]])

onehot = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
A = onehot.fit_transform(A)
B = onehot.transform(B)
```